# Matplotlob set_position() is not working with subplots with constrained_layout

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, axes

I have a set of 4 subplots where the aspect ratio is specified in the first subplot. I understand from [this Github thread](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9274) (which is really helpful) that "sharex just means that they share their x data limits."

I was unable to implement the `get_position()` and `set_position()` recommended on that thread, so I tried a simple test of getting the `ax2` position and just setting it to itself. Why did ax2 move? I don't think it should have moved, this behavior is unexpected.

The underlying question here is, how can I get my subplots x-axes to "line-up" such that the widths are the same, given the initial constraint of aspect defined in the first subplot. I can't just define the aspect in other subplots because they are using different y-axes.

Using Python 3.8

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 5), constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(4, 1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0], aspect=0.7)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0], sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2, 0], sharex=ax1)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[3, 0], sharex=ax1, sharey=ax3)
```

[image]

```
pos2 = ax2.get_position().bounds
ax2.set_position(pos2)
```

[image]

Comment: The easiest thing is to make your figure narrower until the aspect makes your first axes shorter rather than thinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be due to using `constrained_layout`, which matplotlib states is ["experimental"](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html). However, they do state that using `set_position` will manually place the Axes object without the effects of constrained layout:

> A manual call to `set_position` will set the axes so constrained_layout has no effect on it anymore.

You can use `fig.execute_constrained_layout()` to get around this:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 5), constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(4, 1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0], aspect=0.7)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0], sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2, 0], sharex=ax1)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[3, 0], sharex=ax1, sharey=ax3)
fig.execute_constrained_layout()

pos2 = ax2.get_position().bounds
ax2.set_position(pos2)
```

---

If you'd rather just avoid constrained layout, you can try `tight_layout` instead. Make this call before getting positions.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 5))  # constrained_layout is False by default
gs = fig.add_gridspec(4, 1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0], aspect=0.7)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0], sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2, 0], sharex=ax1)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[3, 0], sharex=ax1, sharey=ax3)
fig.tight_layout()                # reconfigure layout before getting positions
```

[image]

```
pos2 = ax2.get_position().bounds
ax2.set_position(pos2)
```

[image]

Comment: wow, thanks so much, a great solution and a great explanation, thank you